# Problema com Calculo de Gastos com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, matemática

Estou tentando fazer um calculo de gastos no sistema porém não estou tendo sucesso.
O sistema funciona da seguinte forma, o Usuario faz um pedido envolvendo 1 ou mais produtos, esses pedidos ficam armazenados em uma tabela.
Cada Produto cadastrado no sistema fica armazenados em outra tabela, tendo os campos padrões, em estoque, custo unitario, ja enviados e pendentes.
O Usuário possuiu duas tabelas, uma para a Filial que ele gerencia e a outra é a conta dos usuarios.

O problema é, ter o valor de pedidos para cada filial. Ou seja, somar quantos itens do produto foram enviados para a filial e depois multiplicar pelo custo dele, e por fim, somar todo o resultado para exibir o gasto total da filial no momento.

Eu tentei usando `while` porém ele exibi várias vezes o mesmo produto em quantidades diferentes para a mesma filial.

**LEGENDAS**

filiais = tabela onde fica todas as filiais cadastradas;

papelaria_itens = tabela onde fica os produtos;

papelaria_solicitacoes = tabela onde fica os pedidos;

papelaria_solicitados = tabela onde fica os produtos solicitados no pedido;

qnt_enviada = Quantidade Enviada;

custo = Custo Unitario por produto;

chns = Código exclusivo para cada dado cadastrado no sistema, funciona como um número de protocolo.

**PHP**
*estou usando o PDO para conexão*

```
$procura_filial = $site->query("SELECT * FROM filiais ORDER BY codigo ASC");
while ($filiais = $procura_filial->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $procura_solicitacoes = $site->query("SELECT * FROM papelaria_solicitacoes WHERE filial = '$filiais->chns'");
    if ($procura_solicitacoes->rowCount() <= 0) {
    }else {
        while($solicitacoes = $procura_solicitacoes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
            $procura_solicitados = $site->query("SELECT * FROM papelaria_solicitados WHERE chns = '$solicitacoes->chns'");
            while ($solicitados = $procura_solicitados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                $reprocura_solicitados = $site->query("SELECT * FROM papelaria_solicitados WHERE filial = '$solicitados->filial' and produtos = '$solicitados->produtos'");
                //SOMA QUANTIDADE ENVIADA DE CADA PRODUTO
                while($soma_qnt = $reprocura_solicitados->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                    $val1 = $soma_qnt->qnt_enviada;
                    $total_cont += $val1;
                    $total_produto_env = $total_cont;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo "Filial: ".$soma_qnt->filial." Produto: ".$soma_qnt->produtos." Enviados: ".$total_produto_env."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vejo que você está indo muito na tabela papelaria_solicitados ou seja está errado.
Você deveria tratar estes cálculos diretamente no banco de dados sem precisar fazer vários  Selects e varios whiles. Seu programa ficara muito lento assim.

Faça algo como:

```
SELECT filial,count(*) as total FROM papelaria_solicitados GROUP BY filial,produtos
```

E depois exibir somente em um while.

Espero ter ajudado, 
Saudações,

Comment: Rodrigo, você poderia me explicar melhor sua sugestão, eu não entendi direito.

Comment: Qual a parte você não entendeu direito?